# mysql select year where value is from previous column

Tags: mysql

I have a table with date and temperature. With the following query I can show a table with the max temperature for each day of the month.

```
SELECT day(data),
    max(if(month(data)='01',Tmax,null)) as maxgen,
    max(if(month(data)='02',Tmax,null)) as maxfeb,
    - the same for each month -
    from estacio 
    where data between '1980-01-01' and '2013-12-31' 
    group by day(data)
```

What I want is find the year when this maxtemp occured and show it next the maxtemp.
What I've tried is make a subquery to find the year for each maxtemp, but I don't know how to refer to the maxtemp in the previous column.

edit: This is what I'm looking for.

```
Day Gen     Feb     Mar      ...   Dec
1   62 1966 62 2012 59 1972  ...   64 2006
2   53 1972 52 1983 61 2004  ...   60 1998

...

31  58 2013         74 1998  ...   57 1965
```

Comment: Not too clear on what you are trying to do, can you give us an example of the output you want?

Comment: other point to clarify is what to do on ties

Answer (score 0):

You should use the following query:

### **Query 1**

```
SELECT day,max(Temp),year(Date)
FROM  estacio    
GROUP BY day(data),year(Date);
```

for month u can use following query:

### **Query 2**

```
SELECT day,max(Temp),month(Date),year(Date)
FROM  estacio    
GROUP BY day(data),Month(Date);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I don't understand the queries. I see the second one outputs the same results as my query but in a format I don't want. I need the same format I've posted.

Comment: Try this one                                                SELECT day(data),
max(if(month(data)='01','Tmax',null)) as maxgen,
max(if(month(data)='02','Tmax',null)) as maxfeb.......
FROM  estacio     
GROUP BY day(data);